# ListView and rows recycling problem

Tags: android

I have this ListView:

[image]

I'm using a custom adapter.

As you see, each row is made of a checkbox, a big TextView, and a little TextView.
All items have defined the little TextView, even the "Item 2" but it's a void string.

The problem comes when I tap the EditText placed in the header of the list:

[image]

The keyboard appears, and the rows are recycled, so the getView method of my adapter is called. In that method I have an if clause where I check if the length of the "optional" text (the little TextView) is greater than 0. In that case I make some room (the space that you can see in the screenshot) and I display it.

The problem is that "Item 2" has the "optional" text initialized but it's void (0-sized). I don't understand why the if clause is executed. But more strangely... the else is also executed! In the else I just show a void string in the little TextView.

Why is this happening? The app is really simple. This is my getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }

    ListItem list_item = items.get(position);

    TextView item_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    TextView item_optional = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_optional);

    item_title.setText(list_item.getTitle());

    // If the task has an optional text, make some room and display it
    if (list_item.hasOptional()) {
        // This portion of code will be executed when you tap the EditText and the keyboard appears, putting the item up in the row
        LayoutParams layout_params = (LayoutParams) item_title.getLayoutParams();
        layout_params.topMargin = 10;
        layout_params.height = -2;  // -2: wrap_content
        item_title.setLayoutParams(layout_params);
        item_optional.setText(list_item.getOptional());
        item_optional.setVisibility(0);
    } else {
        // This portion of code will ALSO be executed when you tap the EditText... why? this should not happen!
        item_optional.setText("");
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

The source code can be seen [**here**](https://gist.github.com/fc545489701344b84006) (github).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modify a recycled view you have no idea what the state of the view is, with respect to how it might have been customized by previous calls to `getView`. The view you are recycling is *not* a fresh-out-the-box inflation of `R.layout.list_row`. Think of it as a "second hand" or "used" view.

So I can see under `if (list_item.hasOptional()..` you make some modification to the  `item_title.getLayoutParams()`. As a view created here may later be recycled for a list item that will fail the check `if (list_item.hasOptional()` under the `else` code block you must reset the values you modify to the default specified in the layout.

Comment: So, I must rollback the values I modify in the if statement, inside the else... is for this reason that it seems both the if and the else are executed at the same time?

Comment: I mean, in the else I must do just the opposite that the if does. Am I correct? My doubt is: why when I tap the TextEdit, it seems that the if and the else statements are executed at the same time?

Comment: In the else clause you must indeed do the opposite of your if clause. And an if and an else cannot be executed at the same time.

Comment: @Romain: Yes I know, but in this case, it seems like both are executed when the keyboard appears. The if clause makes some room, and the else just sets the text to a void string, both behaviors are applied. That's the doubt I have... why? Wouldn't be better to just execute one of them? How could I accomplish it?

Comment: They cannot be both executed at the same time. You made a mistake in your code.

Comment: Ok, now I have noticed what was wrong. I was not understanding how my custom adapter was being called, and that affected the logic that I implemented. At my eyes, it was very strange as it seemed to execute the if and the else at the same time, but fortunately I have identified the confusing issue. Thanks for your help @Jim and @Romain.

Comment: Mmmm... nope, I'm still having a very strange problem with rows recycling that is confusing me again. I'm making a little app to isolate the problem, but if I cannot figure out what is happening I'll start another question with a simpler example.

Comment: You could just disable recycling (removing the `if (convertView == null)` clause would do it). Recycling helps performance on long lists, anything less than a few screenfuls you may not see the difference.

Comment: I have simplified the app and made it very general to show the problem. I have opened a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779747/different-visibility-values-in-each-row-in-a-listview).